FCM notification to be listen on MACOS and Windows desktop for flutter based webview
I have developed one of the desktop application for macos and windows using Flutter, This applications uses webview. Webview is responsible to authentication in the app and FCM, also other features. The main challenge is to listen the FCM notification to these desktop apps.
I have tried with integrating FCM SDK inside flutter code. but dont have any success yet.

You should include your code -- or what kind of help you're otherwise expecting?
